# What's the meaning of "Ça fait une éternité…"?

Tags: sens, expressions, indications-de-temps

What's the meaning of "Eh bien, Philippe, mon vieux. Ça fait une éternité…
" I guess it could be a general greetings like "long time no see" in English, right?

Comment: That's exactly that !

Comment: I would translate it: *It's been ages!*

Comment: [Dictionaries can be useful.](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/%c3%a9ternit%c3%a9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ça fait une éternité..." is a way to say "It has been a long time..." or as you suggest "Long time no see".

You can also say in French "Ça fait longtemps..." but by using "Éternité" it somehow implies that it has been a really long time since you last saw a person or something.

Comment: as jlliagre suggests, "It's been ages!" may reflect the same idea